Are questions relating to LEGO.COM on-topic?
These questions don't relate to a product, but a service run by The LEGO Group (the LEGO website).
Here are a few similar questions based on star-wars and advent-calendar relating to LEGO.COM:

How do I unlock the daily surprises?
Can't open the page to enter my LEGO Advent Calendar code
I have entered codes for days 1-7 on the LEGO Star Wars Calendar site
and now can't enter any more


Dec 2013 Update
We've been getting many more advent-calender questions this advent month:

What are the codes for the LEGO advent game?
Star Wars 2013 Advent calendar codes
We have a 2013 advent calendar and have entered the code from Sunday
but there doesn't seem to be any codes for the 2nd or 3rd
Star wars advent calendar 2013
How do I unlock the sunday surprise on the 2013 Star Wars Advent
Calendar?

Do we really want these kind of questions? Most of these questions would have been closed as 'too localised' prior to June 2012.

closed as too localized
This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only
  relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
  extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
  the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question
  more broadly applicable, visit the help center.


¨Per se, I don't mind questions on LEGO's websites, but my problem with these uestions is that they're very localized in time - there's a good chance LEGO will pull the plug real fast on these pages, and by then the question pretty much makes no sense.
I guess this would be true for a lot of other pages though, but especially for these.

Should we have an off-topic close reason for these kind of questions considering we no longer have a 'too localised' flag?

Not sure - I guess they are similar to the ones we've had on Software support:

LEGO Mindstorms NXT Software Error

We're not really the best people to help with these - as they are really support issues for LEGO to resolve, but we've got a group of people here who may well know an answer.
Personally, I felt the first one (How do I unlock the daily surprises) was fairly "on topic" and easily resolvable.
The second one is certainly dubious, as it's more general Mac/Browser support (probably not even a LEGO Support issue).
The third one I'm unsure of - not having the calendar myself nor the daily codes, I've not seen this issue, so can't comment one way or another.
